# Multiple Multi-class outputs from deep learning model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification

I am working on a Deep Learning Model using the [HAM10000](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/DBW86T) dataset which contains images for differetnt types of skin cancers. There are 7 labels in total to predict which makes this a multi-class classification problem for which a softmax function can be used. These 7 classes have been converted to a bianry class where I have created a column classifying a skin cancer as "malignant" or "benign".

However, I am also trying to analyze the skin color bias in the datasaet with respect to the skin cancer label predictions. Basically, I want to see for predicitons for a given skin cancer say melanoma: how is the prediction being split between "light" and "dark" skin tones.

To this end, I have created another binary column which tells me if an image has more light or dark color in the backgorund. I wanted to know if it's possible for a Deep learning model to return 2 separate multi-class outputs. One way that I can combine the 2 columns together is by summing them together but that would be wrong as 2 of the outputs would be 1 (Based on the combination of 0+0=0, 0+1=1, 1+0=1 and 1+1=2)

The final output that I am targetting is a classification report which breaks this down by the skin color and severity of the cancer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible.

You can use **multi-task neural network**.
or this you need to set the size of the output layer to 9.
The first seven value represents the probability of the following seven classes of skin cancer. The eighth value represents the probability of being "malignant" or "benign". 0 can indicate "completely benign" and 1 can indicate "malignant for sure".
Final value represents how "dark" or "light" the skin is. 0 represents "the darkest" and 0 represents "the lightest".
Once you design the network like this, you should construct the loss function with three values.

The first one (l1) is classification loss from the frist seven outputs. You can use softmax loss that is used commonly in  classification problems.

The second one (l2) is also a classification loss from the eighth output value.

The third one (l3) is regression loss from the final output value.
The total loss can be calculated by with weighted sum of these three values.

L=l1+l2*w2+l3*w3

By constructing the total loss like this, you can train the model to output all the values you want at once.
This is one of the multi-task neural network. This not only allows network to carry out multiple tasks but also increases the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use a multi-task neural network.
In this case, you can create 2 concurent output layers from the last feature in of your network. Let's say you have the final vector of d-dimensions. You should create 2 output layer as follows:

1. Cancer severity prediction, binary classification
2. Skin tone prediction, binary classifciation

The total loss function is sum of the two losses.

That quite straight forward to train a network of that architecture, no special technique required.

Comment: This would be possible with the Keras Functional API right? I have currently implemented something like this by combining the binary labels together as strings and then label encoding them. This combined column then becomes my target predictor.

Comment: Sure, I'm not familiar with Keras Sequential, but I think it is easy.